# Can't make image fit into container

Tags: css

So far the following code has always worked for me in order to make an image fit into its container:

```
img {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: auto;
}
```

Today it doesn't work, the image just appears in its normal size and if it's too big for the container (which has fixed width and height) then it's simply cropped. How is that possible?

Just to give some context here's a screenshot showing Firebug's output when selecting the image followed by another one when selecting its container:

[image]

[image]

Comment: does, `publication or publications` classes have `overflow: hidden` style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following css should work, I would also recommend removing `overflow: hidden` from the parent div

```
img {
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**: I removed the !important after each directive as the OP said it works without.

Comment: Those `!important`s are making my eyes bleed.

Comment: I would agree but, I'm assuming they're to override some other styling since it's only applied `img` tag and not a class or id.

Comment: Glad I was able to help

Comment: It's best to fix the issue than apply an !Important tag - it really is a bad design if you even need to think of using the hack

Comment: @drake035 does my solution work if you remove all the important's?  if so please let me know and I'll update my answer

Comment: An alternative way is to double up on classes to increase specificity. As long as the ruleset you override isn't inline or !important, you more than likely will succeed in overriding intended rulesets.

Comment: @user3299379: yep, works too. I removed them, looks better :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<img>` element then add the following to the `.publication_logo`

> ```
>  .publication_logo {
>    background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-2PeQj-9BqUU/TqWT9Mcu2MI/AAAAAAAACe8/KBU_6AkuyaQ/s1600/Cnet+logo.png)no-repeat;
>    background-size: contain;
>    height: 50px;
>    width: 20%;
>    float: left;
> }
> ```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.publication_logo {
  background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-2PeQj-9BqUU/TqWT9Mcu2MI/AAAAAAAACe8/KBU_6AkuyaQ/s1600/Cnet+logo.png)no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='publication_logo'></div>
```

Comment: I can't do this easily because I get my images dynamically from WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You made `.publication_logo` only `50px` in `height`

However I cannot see an `overflow: hidden` style to the `parent div`